# How to return local temporary table from generated sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have filtering SQL that returns query with uncertain number of columns, and want to use results in stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @RecordSelectionSql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @RecordSelectionSql = (SELECT SQLQUERY FROM RecordSelection WHERE Id = @Id) + ' AND ([Active] = 1)'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @sql += ',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) + name + ' ' + system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@RecordSelectionSql, NULL, 0);

SELECT @sql = N'CREATE TABLE #TmpImport
(' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, N'') + '
);';
EXEC (@sql)

INSERT INTO #TmpImport
EXEC (@RecordSelectionSql)
```

However I am getting error

```
Invalid object name '#TmpImport'.
```

How to properly code this part?

EDIT: added missing condition on RecordSelection

EDIT2:
I cannot use code below because #TmpImport destroyed after @RecordSelectionSql being executed.

```
DECLARE @RecordSelectionSql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @RecordSelectionSql = 'SELECT X.* INTO #TmpImport FROM (' 
    + (SELECT SQLQUERY FROM RecordSelection WHERE Id = @Id) + ' AND ([Active] = 1) AS X'
EXEC (@RecordSelectionSql)
SELECT * FROM #TmpImport
```

Gives the same error

```
Invalid object name '#TmpImport'.
```

Answer (score 5):

Temporary tables are only available within the session that created them.  With Dynamic SQL this means it is not available after the Dynamic SQL has run.  Your options here are to:

1. Create a global temporary table, that will persist outside your session until it is explicitly dropped or cleared out of TempDB another way, using a double hash: `create table ##GlobalTemp`
   --*To incorporate Radu's very relevant comment below: Because this table persists outside your session, you need to make sure you don't create two of them or have two different processes trying to process data within it.  You need to have a way of uniquely identifying the global temp table you want to be dealing with.*
2. You can create a regular table and remember to drop it again afterwards.
3. Include whatever logic that needs to reference the temp table within the Dynamic SQL script

For your particular instance though, you are best off simply executing a `select into` which will generate your table structure from the data that is selected.

Comment: The only problem with the global temporary table (GTT) is that it is visible from other sessions, so you won't be able to create a GTT with the same name, from another session. You'll need to come up with some mechanism to uniquely identify a GTT for each session for when you have to do the cleanup part before closing the session.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu  Very relevant additional info, thanks.  Have added to the above.

Comment: I can create random id
 DECLARE @ db_id int
 SET  @ db_id = CAST(round(RAND() * 2147483647, 0) AS INT) 
select into it using dynamic SQL and drop as EXEC 'DROP TABLE ##TmpImport' +  CAST(@ db_id AS NVARCHAR).
However I cannot use it later in SP without including entire stored procedure logic into dynamic sql.

Comment: @amuliar  Well yes, but then that is the price you pay for trying to use queries saved as text in a table rather than as a stored procedure or view.  What exactly is the reasoning for you doing this?

Comment: Because table RecordSelection contains dymanic selection SQL to process later in SP.

Comment: @amuliar  Yes I understand that, but why?  Why isn't that logic held in views or other stored procedures?  Why does it have to be in a table?

Comment: @iamdave Becuse we are dealing with import chunks what should to be defined, limited and extracted by user using defined rule. These actions stored in generated intermediate SQL as import rule. 
Thank you for your attention. You saved me a lot of time. I have put everything into dynamic SQL, getting rid of temporary tables.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to select into your temp table.

For example

```
SELECT * INTO #TmpImport FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: I don't have SomeTable but I have dynamic SQL in variable @RecordSelectionSql

Comment: @amuliar  Your problem is not that you can't dynamically create the table, but that you cannot reference a temp table created within dynamic SQL.  By using `select * into #temptable` you no longer need to use dynamic SQL to specify your columns.  As such, using `select into` solves every problem you could be having within the context of your question.

Comment: "I have filtering SQL that returns query with uncertain number of columns, and want to use results in stored procedure."
RecordSelection is dynamic, it can contain selection SQL that result with various number of columns and rows.