# create temp table and Store result of execute command at the same time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure where I am running/executing a declared variable which is set to a select query for pivot table, important thing is that that pivot table is transforming column to n number of rows. Yes the rows are not fixed that is why I have problem in creating a temp table with fixed column. What I want is that create a temp table by executing the execute command so the columns would be determined by the select/insert statement.
Below is the query.

```
SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(item) + ',' 
FROM (select distinct item from #TableData ) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) 


set @tequery = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    select Sno, item, SoldValue from #TableData
) mytbl
pivot 
(
    max(ValueInDhs) for GroupName in (' + @cols + ')
) newTable'

execute(@tablequery)
```

I want to store the result of @tequery into a temp table or better this stored procedure should return the result set instead of int as this procedure I have inserted into my entity framework where its showing(after insert) its return type as int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return local temporary table from generated sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721155/how-to-return-local-temporary-table-from-generated-sql)

Comment: please note, code snippets are for executable code, i.e. javascript, html, css, please review my edit to see what i changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a global (##) temp table, although you'd have to be careful of multiple processes doing this at the same time. Here is an abitrary example:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = '
select *
into ##temp -- create global temp table
from   (
          select name
               , create_date = convert(varchar(4), create_date, 102) 
          from   sys.objects) as o
pivot ( count(name) for create_date in ([2017],[2016],[2012], [2009],[2003])
) as p;
'
exec (@sql)

-- if you do not want to use the global table, select it into a temp table
select * into #temp from ##temp

-- and drop the global
drop table ##temp

select * from #temp
```

Comment: The above solution worked but I get into a trouble with this as my entity framework does not return any column, as per the above solution I am retrieving the final result from a ##tab and inside the entity framework it returns only int type, tried to set **SET FMTONLY OFF
--SET FMTONLY ON** no use. just stuck here, when running the stored procedure its returning the result from sql prompt but not from vs 2015 where I am using entity framework 6.0. please provide any solution if you have. thanks

Comment: Can you try select * into real_table instead of into a ##temp and then a select * from real_table?

Comment: That I cannot do because for a real I need to define columns, but my query returns pivot table with n number of columns. I have one of the ##temp table with the fixed column in another store procedure thats working fine, but this is very difficult for me. Please see my pivot query for the n number of columns, and suggest me how I can make this store procedure working.

Comment: **A.J. Schroeder**, one more way is there but for that I need to transpose my column to rows using javascript which I dont know, but if it is done then I can simply call the stored procedure with the fixed columns and transpose that in javascript. but again I don't know how to transpose the column to n number of rows in javascript. Thanks.

Comment: **A.J. Schroeder**, this is my array of object **[{"MyYear":2015,"Type":"A","SoldValue":55},{"MyYear":2014,"Type":"A","SoldValue":58},{"MyYear":2015,"Type":"B","SoldValue":85},.....]**

Comment: **A.J. Schroeder**, thanks I did it, actually I found another website link for the javascript to perform the same as above. and its done. thanks for your effort also.